# how to read specified string from url

Tags: c#, asp.net

Below is my string.  I want to do the following kind of operation: If my url contains "Destinationfolder" then I have to get folder1 and folder2, and the result has to assign to another string one by one.

```
string strpath = @"D:\Multilingual\Destinationfolder\folder1\folder2";
```

Answer (score 3):

You could split by `\`

```
if(strpath.Contains("Destinationfolder")){
    var parts = @"some\stuff".Split('\\').ToList();
    var i = parts.IndexOf("Destinationfolder");
    var folder1 = parts[i+1];
    var folder2 = parts[i+2];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [Path.GetDirectoryName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getdirectoryname.aspx) method in a loop.

Answer (score 0):

```
var folders = strpath.Substring(strpath.IndexOf(@"Destinationfolder\") + 
                               @"Destinationfolder\".Length).Split('\\');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string strpath = @"D:\Multilingual\Destinationfolder\folder1\folder2";
string folderToFind = "Destinationfolder";

var subfolders = new List<string>();
if (strpath.Contains("Destinationfolder"))
{
    subfolders.AddRange(Regex.Replace(strpath, @".*"+folderToFind, "")
         .Trim('\\')
         .Split('\\'));
}
```